# Ux modify timestamp

Tags: bash, perl, unix, timestamp, solaris

I'm trying to write Ux script to change timestamp (add 10years). Its working on Debian but no idea how to do that on Solaris (-d and + 10 years not working)

```
find DIRECTORY -print | while read filename; do
   touch -d "$(date -r "$filename") + 10 years" "$filename"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds ten years in terms of `10*365*24*3600` seconds,

```
find DIRECTORY -print|perl -MFile::stat -lne 'utime((stat($_)->mtime +10*365*24*3600) x2, $_)'
```

in case that `File::stat` is not available,

```
find DIRECTORY -print|perl -lne 'utime(((stat($_))[9] +10*365*24*3600) x2, $_)'
```

Comment: That's not actually 10 years though - it's 3 days short, because of leap years. That may be close enough for the OP  though :)

Comment: @Sobrique yes, correct; that's why I wrote how much seconds in the future.

Comment: @Sobrique `|perl -MTime::Piece -lne 'utime((localtime((stat($_))[9])->add_years(10)->epoch) x2, $_)'` throws `Day too big` with older perl, and Solaris does not have reputation of regular upgrader.

Comment: Works ok on Linux and Perl 5.8.8 - so depends how far behind the curve Solaris is. (I did have to install Time::Piece though).

Answer (score 0):

To change 'mtime' on perl, you need the `utime` function to set it, and the `stat` function to read it.

`Time::Piece` can be used to do the date calculation, using the `add_years` function.

And a traversal can be done using the `File::Find` module.

Giving you something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

use File::Find;
use Time::Piece;

sub set_mtime_10years {
  my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
   $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
       = stat($File::Find::name);

  my $timestamp = localtime ( $mtime );
     $timestamp = $timestamp -> add_years ( 10 );

  #utime sets mtime and atime - set to undef if you only want to change one. 
  utime ( $timestamp -> epoch, #atime
          $timestamp -> epoch, #mtime
          $File::Find::name );
}

find ( \&set_mtime_10years, "." );
```

This will traverse '.', read the mtime of every file, add 10 years to it and write it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Path::Class::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::Rule) and [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class::Rule;
use Time::Piece;

for my $file ( Path::Class::Rule->new->file->all('mydir') ) {
    my $ts = localtime( $file->stat->mtime );
    next if $ts > time;    # Already in the future
    utime( ( $ts->add_years(10)->epoch ) x 2, "$file" );
}
```